# Issue initialising values for typedef field in struct - C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm currently learning C. I've been playing around with typedef and structs, and ran into a strange error (at least to my inexperienced eyes).

I am using a typedef to create a dimensions type (int array of two values), and I have a struct that uses that type def.

Upon trying to specify values for the field in my main, I run into an error:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

The code:

```
typedef int dimensions[2];

struct television
{
    dimensions resolution;
};

int main()
{
    struct television theTV;
    theTV.resolution = {1024, 768};

    return 0;
}
```

It's a very contrived example -- is it possible to initialise the .resolution variable in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instead:

```
struct television theTV = {{1024, 768}};
```

`{}` initializer list can only be use in a declaration and cannot be used in a statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to use assignment to an array, since it is a non-modifiable l-value. However, you can use `memcpy()` with a compound literal:

```
memcpy(theTV.resolution, (dimensions){1024, 768}, sizeof(dimensions));
```

Comment: +1, but I think you mean compound literal instead of array literal